# Twig: how to add an object into multi level object

Tags: twig

In twig template I have an object with multiple levels
I need to add a new object into the multiple object as the sub object

```
{%
   set data = {
     'first': 'First',
     'data': {
        'val_1': 'val_1'
       }
     }
%}
```

this should be added to data `val_2: val_2`

expected result:

```
{%
   set data = {
     'first': 'First',
     'data': {
        'val_1': 'val_1',
        'val_2': 'val_2'
       }
     }
%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in Twig terminology, that's not an object or a key-value array but a *hash* ([see Twig's documentation of literals](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#literals)).

You can't add an item to a hash e.g. by doing `{% set data.second = 'Second' %}`. Instead you need to use the [merge filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html):

```
{%
    set data = data|merge({
        second: 'Second',
    })
%}

{{ dump(data) }}

{# Prints this:

array(3) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(5) "First"
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["val_1"]=>
    string(5) "val_1"
  }
  ["second"]=>
  string(6) "Second"
}

#}
```

So, to add an item to a hash inside a hash, you need to use the merge filter twice:

```
{%
    set data = data|merge({
        data: data.data|merge({
            val_2: 'val_2',
        }),
    })
%}

{# Prints this:

array(3) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(5) "First"
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["val_1"]=>
    string(5) "val_1"
    ["val_2"]=>
    string(5) "val_2"
  }
  ["second"]=>
  string(6) "Second"
}

#}
```

If you do lots of this kind of variable manipulation in Twig, it might be a sign that some of that code might be better put in a controller or model or whatever.